# Why does getToken() run multiple times when I call it onAuthStateChanged()?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase Authentication in a basic react app.  I have a function in my data context provider to fetch the FCM token upon sign in/ sign out actions.

```
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    setUserData(user);
    requestPermission(user);
  });
```

Inside requestPermission(user), I request notification permission and run a simple getToken() function:

```
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: process.env.REACT_APP_VAPID_KEY }).then(
        (currentToken) => {
          if (currentToken) {
            console.log('current token for client: ', currentToken);
            // Track the token -> client mapping, by sending to backend server
            // show on the UI that permission is secured
            // addUserTokenToDatabase(userData, currentToken);
          } else {
            console.log(
              'No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.',
            );
          }
        },
      );
```

A different current token then displays six times consecutively as soon as I sign in.  Is that typical behavior?